# mysql On Duplicate value in field, insert new row with new value

Tags: mysql

I want to add a new record in a table if duplicate value enters in a unique field. I don't want to update the existing one but want to add a new record by modifying the unique field value.
Is this possible in mysql?

Comment: don't want to update existing record but want to insert new by modifying the duplicated value eg if field "name" has "test1" value in the first record. I want to add test2 in another record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Edited after user comment on this post:

You need [write table locking](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/)  on both of those two processes.

A WRITE lock has the following features:

- The only session that holds the lock of a table can read and write data from the table.
- Other sessions cannot read data from and write data to the table until the WRITE lock is released.

Also look at [SQL UNIQUE Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/sqL/sql_unique.asp)

**BEFORE EDIT:**

Yes it is possible. And it took me awhile to figure it out. I build this on your input and compering values as test1, test2 etc, where test is always the same and has trailing number. As you specified.

It can be done as [MySQL TRANSACTION](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx) in 4 steps.

Lets say you have table `testT` where name is unique to insure we have no doubles.

```
| id  | name  |
| --- | ----- |
| 1   | test1 |
| 2   | test3 |
```

And you want to insert a new item with name test1 we set is as:

```
SET @newName = 'test1';
```

Then we need to check if it already exists in table:

```
SELECT @check:=COUNT(*) FROM testT WHERE name = @newName;
```

We do a count here to get true or false and save it as `@check` here so we can compare it later. This will result into `1 row` as `test1` already exists in table.

Next we do another selection to get the highest number of test* and store it as `@number`, this next query selects all tests and does a SUBSTRING after 4 latter's giving us all numbers after first 4 latter's. (99999999999) numbers actually just to be sure we don't miss any but in our case result is only "3" because that is last record "`test3`" in table.

```
SELECT 
    @number:= SUBSTRING(name,5,99999999999) 
FROM testT;
```

Now we can do an insert:

```
INSERT INTO testT(name)
VALUES
(
    IF(@check = "", @newName , CONCAT(LEFT(@newName,4),RIGHT(@number,1)+1)
)
);
```

This tries to insert our `@newName` into table under IF condition, and that is if our  `@check` is empty then he will insert `@newName`, if not it will take word test out of string and append a highest `@number` from earlier and add + 1 too it.

So result for `@newName = 'test1'` is below. If you change this into  `@newName = 'test3'` result wold be same new insert `test4`.

```
**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

    SET @newName = 'test1';   

---

**Query #1**

    SELECT * FROM testT
     ORDER BY id;

| id  | name  |
| --- | ----- |
| 1   | test1 |
| 2   | test3 |
| 3   | test4 |

---
```

And if you change it in ANY test* that number does not already exists it will insert it normally. In case below: `@newName = 'test6'`

```
SET @newName = 'test6';
    **Query #1**

        SELECT * FROM testT
         ORDER BY id;

    | id  | name  |
    | --- | ----- |
    | 1   | test1 |
    | 2   | test3 |
    | 3   | test6 |
```

This way an insert will always be made.

You can play with this here : [View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n3mX2mE38jHY7c7Ti1BGP8/5) just by changing `SET @newName = 'test6'`

I am no expert and it took me couple of hours to figure this way out, as I wanted to know if this was even possible. 
And I would appreciate if any other user can suggestion any other way or improve my method.

Comment: This is clever but fails to take into account the concurrent nature of MySQL, i.e. if two processes attempt to `INSERT` a new record at the same moment, they will each attempt to use the same `name`, and the second one which gets executed will still fail.

Comment: Thank you. That can be fixed with WRITE locking table  while doing this transaction if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, but note that you'll have to generate the new `name` *after* the lock is created.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of locking the table right at start of transaction. That should do it I believe.

Comment: @ikiK , kmoser thanks for your answer.
the main problem was when two processes attempt to INSERT a new record at the same moment, they each attempt to use the same name. so the same record inserted.
I am using codeigniter for this. and MyISAM is the storage engine

Comment: @NaveedJasim I have make an edit to my answer, also next time be more specific to start with. It took you 3 posts to finally post an description of actual problem.

Comment: @ikiK thank you so much for the help and sorry for the short and unclear description. if I use a unique constraint then it will produce an error or will not enter the record on duplicate value. how I will handle this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @NaveedJasim That wont even happen if you use table locking, if you implement that, that kind of situation wont even happen. Read the link about locking. Unique is there just to ease your mind. You don't need it if you implement locking the right way, but while you test your locking it is good too have it, to make sure you don't get double values while testing. And unique  will produce an error AND wont insert data on duplicate value.

Comment: @NaveedJasim Or you can turn on you table locking, setup an unique AND construct your insert queries as transactions just as I shown you example in post above. But I belive table locking is only thing you need and easy to implement. Read about it.

Comment: @NaveedJasim One of those ways I have mentioned is what you need. It all deepens on your quires and data. And without seeing that, no way no one can say to you what exactly you need.

Comment: @ikiK thank you for your help. I try to use table level locking