# Tracking recurring events in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to track Trending Topics from Twitter in a MySQL database.
Therefore, I request the trending topic from Twitter every 15 minutes and insert it into my database. If the trending topic exists already, I update the end datetime to the current datetime value:

```
INSERT INTO database(trend, start_datetime, end_datetime)
VALUES('hashtag', '2020-03-01 00:00:00', '2020-03-01 11:00:00')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE end_datetime='2020-03-01 11:00:00'
```

However, I’ve the problem that some trending topics are recurring (e.g. #MondayMorning is recurring every week) and I can’t factor this in with my setup. Is there a way to UPDATE the end_datetime only when the end_datetime value in the table is not older than 2 hours and otherwise INSERT a new entry with a fresh start_datetime?

Comment: What is your  key? If its hashtag, how will you store MondayMorning again as a new entry with new end_datetime? your logic might be wrong, width  the date itself you can do calculations and offsets.

Comment: @ikiK My key is Hashtag + start_datetime, so I could use the same Hashtag with multiple different start_datetimes. I just don’t know how to insert a new entry instead of updating the old one, based on the time difference between end_datetime and now().

Comment: I was thinking about it for a while and I don't know how to do this, if even possible in SQL. But I'm no expert. I know this this can easily be done in PHP for example. Bunch of ifs and cases. As far as calculating difference you can do it with https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_add/ . No problem there.

Comment: I made other day this, it little similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61045360/mysql-on-duplicate-value-in-field-insert-new-row-with-new-value/61052264#61052264 (read before edit part). Maybe some idea comes to your mind.